# What is the estimator of $P(X=0)$ for $X\sim\operatorname{Poisson}$

Tags: statistics

Let $X\sim\operatorname{Poisson}$.
What is the estimator of $P(X=0)$ by maximum likelihood method. 
If it based on random sample of size $n$
Thank you

Comment: "The" estimator? Based on what? With respect to which criterion?

Comment: Sorry, it base on Maximum likelihood method

Comment: Based on what? A sample of size 1? Of size n? Independent? Etc.

Comment: Based on random sample of size n

Comment: And an *independent* sample? You know, all this should have been in the question from the beginning...

Comment: Yes, it's independent . I say "random sample" it always mean i.i.d.

Comment: No it does not--but now we know you mean i.i.d.

Comment: I've voted to re-open.  The question has undergone some editing since the terse initial posting.  It's perfectly clear what it's about.

Answer (score 1):

If you observe only $X$, then the MLE for $\lambda=\mathbb EX$ is just $\widehat\lambda=X$.

MLEs have a nice equivariance property not shared by unbiased estimators, method-of-moments estimators, or other sorts of estimators: the MLE of $g(\lambda)$ is $g$ of the MLE of $\lambda$.  Thus if you know that $\Pr(X=0)=e^{-\lambda}$, then you can conclude that the MLE for $\Pr(X=0)$ is $e^{-\widehat \lambda} = e^{-X}$.

---

You could of course do it by brute force: Let $\alpha=e^{-\lambda}$, so $\lambda=-\log\alpha$.  Then
$$
L(\alpha)=\Pr(X=x) = \frac{\lambda^x e^{-\lambda}}{x!} = \frac{(-\log\alpha)^x\alpha}{x!}.
$$
Then
$$
\ell(\alpha)=\log L(\alpha) = x\log(-\log\alpha) + \log\alpha+\text{constant},
$$
and then
$$
\ell\,'(\alpha) = x\frac{-1/\alpha}{(-\log\alpha)}+\frac1\alpha = \frac1\alpha\left(\frac{x}{\log\alpha}+1\right).
$$
For $\alpha>0$, this is $0$ only when $\alpha=e^{-x}$.  Then there's a bit more work to do to show that this is indeed a global maximum.

Comment: Thank you :)) if it based on random sample of size n . The answer is e^-(XBar) ?

Comment: As an aside, you may also consider the properties of the [James-Stein Estimator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James%E2%80%93Stein_estimator) if you ever encounter an example of this with dimensionality of three or more.

Comment: I based my answer on a sample of size $1$, because that's what the question appeared to say.  But in case of an larger i.i.d. sample, it is $e^{-\overline X}$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Thank you so much Michael , it's my final test question. I'm answered e^-(Xbar) but i'm not sure about it. Thank you again.

Comment: @EMS : I appreciate your pointing this out, but I don't think it's very relevant to the question, since the question was about an MLE.